# How do I install Sage on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 15.04, sagemath

I've tried adding the aims/sagemath ppa (https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath) to Ubuntu 15.04 but, unfortunately, however, this ppa only includes packages for 12.04-14.10. Is there a way around this? Like will the 14.10 version suffice and if so how do I install it via APT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Sage is not available for 15.04 yet.  It says that the package is still pending.  It should be available shortly.

Once its available, you can add the repository, and install sage.

[image]